# Does .NET Framework's WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetReturnUrlFromResponse have .NET Core equivalent?

Tags: ws-federation

WSFederationAuthenticationModule.GetReturnUrlFromResponse method which documentation says that the URL of the page that waws originally request by the client is preserved. Is there something like this in .NET Core > 3.x